# C++/Qt 5 GStreamer continues loop

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer

I'm currently trying to experiment with GSteamer playing a video on loop. I have it currently implemented like this:

```
void VPlayer::playFile(QString video_filename, bool loop)
{
    m_isLooping = loop;
    QString cmdstr = "gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=" + video_filename + " ! qtdemux ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 ! vpudec frame-drop=0 ! queue ! imxv4l2sink device=/dev/video16";
    GError **l_error = NULL;;
    m_gst_pipeline = gst_parse_launch (cmdstr.toUtf8().data(), l_error);

    m_gst_bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE(m_gst_pipeline));
    gst_bus_set_sync_handler (m_gst_bus, GStreamerBusCallback, this, nullptr);
    gst_object_ref (m_gst_bus);
    gst_object_ref(m_gst_pipeline);

    gst_element_set_state (m_gst_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_element_seek_simple (m_gst_pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, 0);
    gst_element_set_state (m_gst_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}

GstBusSyncReply VPlayer::GStreamerBusCallback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data)
{
    VPlayer* player = (VPlayer*) data;
    GstElement *pipeline = player->getPipeline();
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
    {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        /* restart playback if at end */
        qDebug() << "PLAYBACK FINISHED";
        if(player->isLooping())
        {
            qDebug() << "LOOPING";
            gst_element_seek_simple (pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, 0);
            gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return GST_BUS_PASS;
}
```

When I run this example I get the EOS as expected and also the debug output is ok, but instead of seeking the image freezes and nothing happens. Also the looping does not seem to continue.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

At least this needs to be fixed:

```
GError *l_error = NULL;
m_gst_pipeline = gst_parse_launch (cmdstr.toUtf8().data(), &l_error);
```

and I'm assuming you call `gst_init(...);` somewhere.

Comment: I read something about threading here - can you put your code into a sample project where everything is served from main()? Just to make sure you do not run into threading issues. Even calling qDebug() can cause issues depending on the platform.

Comment: The solution was to revert back to using gstreamer main loop and put it in a separate worker thread as to not block Qt eventloop